# Using the .Restrict method in Outlook VBA to filter on single recipient email address

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010, outlook-filter

I have code in Access that gets all emails in the user's Inbox that are sent by an individual email address. This code (simplified, below) works fine:

```
Dim outItems as Outlook.Items
Dim strEMAddress as string
Dim outFolder as Outlook.MAPIFolder

Set outFolder = outNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set outItems = outFolder.Items

str="my@email.com"

Set outItems = outItems.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress] = " & "'" & strEMAddress & "'")
```

I am looking for something that will do likewise on the SentMails folder, restricting the items to those sent to a specific email address.

I know this is complicated by the fact that .Recipients is a collection (as items can/do have more than one recipient).  I am hoping there is a way to return a list of items that contain the email address I am looking for in any of the sent fields (To/CC/bcc - but happy with just To if this is easier).

I have searched online and found .To is no good (is not the email address) and I can't get pseudo code such as this work:

```
 Set outItems = outItems.Restrict("[Recipients] = " & "'" & strEMAddress & "'")
```

Comment: Are you referencing the Sent Items folder correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the DASL query as the filter string in your **items.restrict** method.

For example to find all mails i sent to Ali Raza i use the following

```
str_fltr = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto"" ci_phrasematch '%Ali Raza%'"
```

The good thing about the above DASL query is that it returns matches with multiple recepients whether if you use the jet syntax for searching resultx will only contain items with one recipient. Jet syntax is the one that you are currently using. You should use the **[To]** property rather than **[Recipients]**

Here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc513841%28v=office.12%29.aspx#SearchingOutlookData_Overview is good place where you can learn almost everything about searching in outlook.

Here http://www.msoffice.us/Outlook/PDF/%28Outlook%202010%29%20Common%20DASL%20Property%20Tags.pdf is a list of common DASL tags which will come in handy if you get a grip on DASL syntax.

Comment: Thanks S.aad. Question:

When using this method, what fields exactly is "displayto" referring to ie does it look at the email address, or the display name, or both? It's the actual email address I need to be filtering against.

Comment: The query on displayto corresponds to the PR_DISPLAY_TO MAPI property, which in most cases does not contains addresses.

Answer (score 2):

For multiple ***`[TO/CC/BCC]`*** filter example would be...

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim Filter As String
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Folder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

    Filter = "@SQL=" & "urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto" & _
                       " Like '%John Doe%' Or " & _
                       "urn:schemas:httpmail:displaycc" & _
                       " Like '%John Doe%' Or " & _
                       "urn:schemas:httpmail:displaybcc" & _
                       " Like '%John Doe%'"

    Set Items = Folder.Items.Restrict(Filter)

    Msg = Items.Count & " Items in " & Folder.Name & " Folder"

    If MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
            Debug.Print Items(i) 'Immediate Window
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

now remember if the display name is **`John.Doe@Email.com`** then filter should be `%John.Doe@Email.com%` else use `%John Doe%`

Comment: That will work only if the email address if a part of To/CC/BCC display name. In most cases that is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) is an option (I am its author), you can use `RDOFolder`.[Items.Restrict](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOItems.htm) - unlike Outlook Object Model, it does expand `To`/`CC`/`BCC` queries into recipient sub restrictions on `PR_DISPLAY_NAME` and `PR_EMAIL_ADDRESS` properties on each recipient (`RES_SUBRESTRICTION` / `PR_MESSAGE_RECIPIENTS` / `RES_OR` / `PR_DISPLAY_NAME` | `PR_EMAIL_ADDRESS`).

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set Folder = Session.GetFolderFromID(Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.EntryID)
set restrItems = Folder.Items.Restrict(" TO = 'user@domain.demo' ")
```

You can also specify `Recipients` property in the SQL query - it will be matched against recipients of all types (to/cc/bb):

```
set restrItems = Folder.Items.Restrict(" Recipients = 'user@domain.demo' ")
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thanks for this, but I am afraid Redemption isn't really an option. Thanks for trying all the same, and any other ideas welcome

Comment: Yap `(" Recipients = 'user@domain.demo' ")` should work as well

Comment: Hi, I read your comment on the other answers and I do agree with you. Same as the OP, redemption is not an option for me. Is there any other method I can look into for obtaining the `.To` email address?

Comment: Not much you can do unless you can loop through the folder items and open each item at a time. Which will be hundreds of times slower. Or switch to C++ or Delphi and write your own Extended MAPI code.